# Sending message from Python server to Android client with sockets

Tags: python, android, kotlin, sockets, server

i'm trying to implement a bidirectional socket connection between a Python server and an Android client.
The problem is that the server receives the messages sent from the client, but not viceversa.

This is the code:

**CLIENT SIDE, kotlin**

**MainActivity.kt**

```
package com.example.server_continuous

import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val host = "192.168.0.***"
        val port = 8888
        val dataToSend = "Berlino"

        val netClient = NetClient(host, port)
        val result = try {
            SendDataTask().execute(netClient, dataToSend).get()
        } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            "Error: ${e.message}"
        } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            "Error: ${e.message}"
        }
        Log.d("Result",result)

        // Process the result as needed
        println(result)
    }

    inner class SendDataTask : AsyncTask<Any, Void, String>() {
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: Any): String {
            val netClient = params[0] as NetClient
            val dataToSend = params[1] as String

            netClient.sendDataWithString(dataToSend)
            return netClient.receiveDataFromServer()
        }
    }

}
```

**NetClient.kt**

```
package com.example.server_continuous


import android.util.Log
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.Socket

class NetClient(private val host: String, private val port: Int) {

    companion object {
        const val BUFFER_SIZE = 30
    }

    private var socket: Socket? = null
    private var out: PrintWriter? = null
    private var `in`: BufferedReader? = null

    private fun connectWithServer() {
        try {
            if (socket == null) {
                socket = Socket(host, port)
                out = PrintWriter(socket!!.getOutputStream(), true)
                `in` = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(socket!!.getInputStream()))
            }
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun disConnectWithServer() {
        if (socket != null) {
            if (socket!!.isConnected) {
                try {
                    `in`?.close()
                    out?.close()
                    socket?.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun sendDataWithString(message: String) {
        if (message != null) {
            connectWithServer()
            out?.write(message)
            out?.flush()
        }
    }

    fun receiveDataFromServer(): String {
        return try {
            val response = StringBuilder() // Use StringBuilder to efficiently build the response

            connectWithServer()
            var line: String? = null

            // Read the response line by line
            while (`in`?.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                println("Message: $line")
                line?.let { Log.d("mex", it) }
                response.append(line) // Append each line to the StringBuilder
            }

            disConnectWithServer()
            response.toString() // Convert the StringBuilder to a String and return the response
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            "Error receiving response: ${e.message}"
        }
    }

}
```

**SERVER, python**

```
import socket
import json
import threading


# Define the server's IP address and port number
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
server_port = 8888


# Create a socket object (standard options)
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

print('Socket created')

# Bind the socket to the IP address and port
try:
    server_socket.bind((server_ip, server_port))
except socket.error as err:
    print('Bind failed, error code:', err)

print('Socket bind success')

# Listen for incoming connections
server_socket.listen(1)  # Listen for only one client connection
print('Server listening on {}:{}'.format(server_ip, server_port))

# Variable to store the connected client socket
client_socket = None

# Flag to indicate server termination
terminate = False

# Function for handling individual client connections
def handle_client():
    global client_socket
    global received_data

    while True:
        if client_socket:
            # Receive data from the client
            data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            client_socket.sendall("Server 123".encode('utf-8'))
            if not data:
                break

            print('Received from client:', data)

                            

    # # Client connection closed
    # if client_socket:
    #     client_socket.close()
    # client_socket = None

# Function for accepting client connection
def accept_connection():
    global client_socket
    global terminate

    while not terminate:
        try:
            # Accept client connection
            # Client socket and address allow us to reply back to the client
            client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
            print('Connected to client:', client_address)

            # Start a thread for handling the client connection
            client_thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client,daemon=True)
            client_thread.start()

            # Wait for the client thread to complete
            client_thread.join()

            # # Close the client socket
            # if client_socket:
            #     client_socket.close()
            # client_socket = None
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            # Terminate the server on keyboard interrupt - DOES NOT WORK
            terminate = True

# Start a thread for accepting client connection
accept_thread = threading.Thread(target=accept_connection,daemon=True)
accept_thread.start()

try:
    # Wait for the accept thread to complete
    accept_thread.join()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Terminate the server on keyboard interrupt - DOES NOT WORK
    terminate = True

# Close the server socket
server_socket.close()
print('Server connection closed')
```

Any clue?

When the app starts, the python server receive correctly the message "Berlino", but on the other hand I'm not able to receive or manage correctly the "Server 123" message sent from the server.

I'm pretty sure that the server is sending correctly the message on the socket, since trying with a Python client it worked.

In the Android code I would like to print the received message in the Log for example.

**UPDATE**
I've added the newline character to the message on the server side, and now I can see the "mex" log on Logcat. Anyway the code seems to remain stuck into the while loop inside the receiveDataFromServer() function.

Comment: The client tries to read lines. But the server does not send a line. Only a string.

Comment: What is a line?

Comment: @blackapps You are right, now i've added the newline character to the message on the server side and it's partially working, 
I've found that the code remains stuck into the while loop of the receiveDataFromServer() function

Comment: If only one line is sent then do not try to receive more lines.

Answer (score 0):

To connect to the server, you use an `AssyncTask`, so you can't return a result of the `doInBackground` function to the Main Thread. The Main Thread will not wait for the Assync Task to end, so you can't get the result there. Instead, in your `SendDataTask` class you can override the function:

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: String) {
      Log.d("Result",result)
}
```

This function will execute after the `doInBackground` function finish, and get what you returned there. If you need, there you can change an observable var, and that will update your view.

PS: You should try to use Coroutines instead of Assync Task, because this class was deprecated.